# Using ifelse() with R and text removal: how to handle NA values?

Tags: r

I have a column of data that has mixed units. I'm trying to use `ifelse()` to standardize the minute values to hours, which is the other unit.

Starting with data like:

```
test_df <- data.frame(
  median_playtime = c("2.5 hours", "9 minutes", "20 hours")
)
```

I'm trying this:

```
  test_df$median_playtime_hours <- ifelse(

  #if the data has hours in it, then...
  test = length(grep("hours", as.character(test_df$median_playtime) ,value=FALSE)) == 1

  #text removal if it contains hours
  ,as.numeric(gsub(pattern = " hours", replacement = "", x = as.character(test_df$median_playtime)))

  #otherwise, remove minutes text and divide by 60
  ,as.numeric(gsub(pattern = " minutes", replacement = "", x = test_df$median_playtime)) / 60
)
```

Each conditional line works ok but produces NAs for the mismatch cases, so the end result is NAs across the board. Is there a way to either ignore the NAs or merge the two conditions so the NAs aren't the only value returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an issue with your `test` - it only returns a single value of `FALSE`. If you instead use `grepl` to test you get your expected result:

```
test_df$median_playtime_hours <- ifelse(
    #if the data has hours in it, then...
    test = grepl("hours", as.character(test_df$median_playtime)),
    #text removal if it contains hours
    as.numeric(gsub(pattern = " hours", replacement = "", x = as.character(test_df$median_playtime))),
    #otherwise, remove minutes text and divide by 60
    as.numeric(gsub(pattern = " minutes", replacement = "", x = test_df$median_playtime)) / 60
)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you separate numbers from units, a lookup table works nicely:

```r
library(tidyverse)

test_df <- tibble(
    median_playtime = c("2.5 hours", "9 minutes", "20 hours")
)

test_df %>% 
    separate(median_playtime, c('time', 'units'), sep = '\\s', convert = TRUE) %>% 
    mutate(seconds = time *  c('minutes' = 60, 'hours' = 60*60)[units])
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>    time units   seconds
#>   <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
#> 1   2.5 hours      9000
#> 2   9   minutes     540
#> 3  20   hours     72000
```

If you want to keep it all in base,

```r
test_df <- data.frame(
    median_playtime = c("2.5 hours", "9 minutes", "20 hours"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

test_df$seconds <- sapply(strsplit(test_df$median_playtime, "\\s"), function(x){
    as.numeric(x[1]) * c(minutes = 60, hours = 60*60)[x[2]]
})

test_df
#>   median_playtime seconds
#> 1       2.5 hours    9000
#> 2       9 minutes     540
#> 3        20 hours   72000
```